# zsh process substitution on array elements

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to write a zsh script that takes one or more URLs as arguments and runs a command (in this case, the ImageMagick `montage` command) for each of them.  The goal is to be able to create a montage of a set of URLs.

I can, of course, download each of the URLs and pass the resulting filenames to `montage`, but zsh's process substitution seems like it would simplify things.

If I'm just doing it manually for a set of URLs, that's pretty easy:

```
montage -size 640x480 -geometry +2+2            \
     =(curl -s https://i.imgur.com/fSgnUKW.jpg) \
     =(curl -s https://i.imgur.com/6xIgEx2.jpg) \
     output.jpg
```

but in a script where I want to take the URLs as arguments, I can't figure out how to get it working.

I know about the `a${^foo}b` trick to do sort of a list comprehension thing, so I can do this:

```
local -a urls
urls=(https://i.imgur.com/fSgnUKW.jpg https://i.imgur.com/6xIgEx2.jpg)
echo "=(curl -s "${^urls}")"
```

which produces this output:

```
=(curl -s https://i.imgur.com/fSgnUKW.jpg) =(curl -s https://i.imgur.com/6xIgEx2.jpg)
```

This is exactly what I'd want in the `montage` command-line above, but I can't do this:

```
local -a args
args=('=(curl -s '${^urls}')')
montage -size 640x480 -geometry +2+2 $args output.jpg
```

If I run those commands with zsh -x, I see this:

```
+./foo:12> montage -size 640x480 -geometry +2+2 '=(curl -s https://i.imgur.com/fSgnUKW.jpg)' '=(curl -s https://i.imgur.com/6xIgEx2.jpg)' output.jpg
```

In other words, it seems to be quoting the elements of `args` when it expands them.  What I want it to do is just put them in without the quotes, and do the process substitution so that the `=(curl -s ...)` executes and returns the filename of the output.

I found that there's a "parameter expansion flag" `(Q)` that says it removes a level of quotes from the result, but changing the last line to:

```
montage -size 640x480 -geometry +2+2 ${(Q)args} output.jpg
```

doesn't help -- I suspect because it's an array.  Is there any way to expand the array elements, without quotes, and do the process substitution, so that I get the temporary filename for each of the `curl` processes' outputs?

Comment: ImageMagick should be able to access your input file as a list directly without the curl. However, you may have to edit your policy.xml file if policy.xml has been restricted on HTTPS access. Sorry I do not know zsh.

Comment: @fmw42 that definitely helps!  I did not know that ImageMagick restricts HTTPS urls.  The solution was to add  ```<policy domain="coder" rights="read" pattern="HTTPS" />``` to my policy.xml```.  I guess this question is academic at this point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `args` is in the end nothing more then a "string", if you want to evaluate the above you have to parse it with `eval`

```
eval montage -size 640x480 -geometry +2+2 $args output.jpg
```

> **`man zshall` :** `eval [ arg ... ]`
>
> Read the arguments as input to the shell and execute the resulting command(s) in the current shell process.  The return status
>   is the same as if the commands had been executed directly by the
>   shell; if there are no args
>                 or they contain no commands (i.e. are an empty string or whitespace) the return status is zero.

What it essentialy does is, it concatenates the various arguments of `eval` in one big space-separated string and then executes that string by the shell.